# gcloud info --format json doesn't work

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When running `gcloud info --format json` on a GCE instance I get the following exception :

```
% gcloud info --format json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 171, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 385, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 930, in Run
    output_formatter(result)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 922, in Format
    resource_printer.Print(obj, args.format or 'yaml', out=log.out)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/resource_printer.py", line 421, in Print
    formatter.PrintSingleRecord(resources)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/resource_printer.py", line 88, in PrintSingleRecord
    separators=(',', ': '))
  File "/home/Tradelab/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/home/Tradelab/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/home/Tradelab/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <__calliope__command__.93a535615504421c846125f4c0a6cb7e.gcloud.info.InfoHolder object at 0x7f70752ad950> is not JSON serializable
```

I can avoid this by editing `resource-printer.py` but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this, it appears to be a bug. I sent it to the `gcloud` team.

Comment: It is indeed a bug; the Cloud SDK team will work on this.

Comment: The bug will be fixed in the Cloud SDK 0.9.83 release.